# Cronjob on Amazon EC2 Deleted?

Tags: cron, amazon-ec2

I had a cronjob set up to run a php script daily, which went well for about a month. Today, I realized it didn't run the script so I opened up the crontab. The crontab is completely empty - what happened?

I don't know too much about cronjobs, but as far as I understand, they do not delete themselves if the server is reset. How can I make sure cronjobs are always running and that it doesnt get deleted?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with EC2.  A cron job is completely internal to your server.  You don't provide sufficient information to diagnose your problem.  There are a number of ways to set up cron jobs on Linux, not a single file to open.

Comment: Is your Instance run under Auto Scaling?

Comment: Make sure you are under the right user

Comment: @Eric I originally set it up with crontab -e. Now, when I use that same command, it shows just a few comments (which I didnt write and came with the cron). I'm mostly looking for a reason that it would have cleared/reset itself.

Comment: I am getting this issue not with EC2, but a linux server sitting right behind me. Keeps reverting its crontab to an earlier version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably under a different user. Check root user `sudo crontab -e`. Each user has it's own crontab and there's one for the whole system. Note: Through the crontab configuration you can disable per-user crontabs.

Comment: Well...this is really weird. I created a new cron job, tested it, and just let it be. Today, I logged in but I can't find the new cronjob I wrote in either root or my normal user. However, I found my original cronjob.

I'm going to chalk this one up to my insanity - maybe I was seriously tripping out when I couldn't find my original cronjob. The thing is, it's supposed to send a SMS text out to each of my users, and no texts were sent....

Comment: I am thinking you have multiple instances and you mixed them up :D Maybe in different regions.. Check it out.